# How to do my own custom list?

Tags: android

How to do my own custom list? I mean, that each element of list will be looking like I want.

Comment: You'll have to be more specific than that. What is the list for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Create a custom list item row layout**
You have to create a custom list row item in the layout folder, just like you define the usual activity layouts. There you place your icons, TextViews etc and place them properly.

**Override the specific adapter you need**
You then need to override the specific adapter you need in order to associate the data from your curso / object list with your layout xml element. This is usually done by overriding the `getView`or `bindView` method of the adapter of your choice (ResourceCursorAdapter, ArrayAdapter,..).

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
   if(convertView == null){
      convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item, parent, false);
   }


   TextView someTextViewOnMyRowLayout = (TextView)findViewById(...);
   someTextViewOnMyRowLayout.setText(...);

   return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an xml file which acts as an element that looks like you want..
and assign that to the list using inflators and adapters..

Try this.. 
http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/  , 
http://www.androidpeople.com/android-custom-listview-tutorial-example/